# How to cite references from more than on sources in beamer?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing

I want to cite references from different filenames. To be clear, let's say some of my references are saved as `myref1.bib` and some are found in the file named `myref2.bib`. If I  want to cite those in the first file, I can use

```
 \bibliography{myref1.bib}
```

So, how can one also cite those in `myref2.bib`? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a comma separated list of files in the `\bibliography` macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myref1.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author = {Einstein, A.},
    title = {Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume = {354},
    number = {7},
    doi = {10.1002/andp.19163540702},
    pages = {769--822},
    year = {1916}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myref2.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\cite{einstein}\cite{knuth}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{myref1,myref2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @iGada You're welcome!